# How can I replace "|~||~||~||~|" with a blank in R?

Tags: r

I have some sort of data preparation where at end of some string "|~||~||~||~|"  or "|~||~|" characters are coming. I am unable to remove it via gsub() and str_replace() functions. Please advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just need to escape `|`, i.e. `\\|`:

```
string <- c("cat|~||~||~||~|", "mouse|~||~|", "dogg")
sub("\\|~.+$", "", string)
[1] "cat"   "mouse" "dogg"
```

Alternatively you can specify `fixed = TRUE`:

```
gsub("|~|", "", string, fixed = TRUE)
[1] "cat"   "mouse" "dogg"
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the character "|" is a special or metacharacter that regex interprets as union/or. You can double scape it with "\" or force regex to expect the literal charachter with "[|]".

Try this:

```
string <- "|~||~||~||~|somecharacters1234"
gsub("[|].*[|]","", string)
```

Result:

```
 [1] "somecharacters1234"
```

Comment: I believe you have swapped the meta-characters `*.`, try it with a string that *ends* in the OP's pattern and see the result. Then try `gsub("[|].*[|]","", string)`.